# Unable to setState with props in class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a class component which can be viewed by 2 screens  and 1 screen is passing props and 1 is not. so i want to set default value "" 0r empty if there are no props and if there are props then value should be based on props. but i'm unable to do so. Any help will be appreciated.. flow is like this.. main screen==> rating(without props so state should be empty)==>search screen==>rating(with props. state should get value from state)

```
class Rating extends Component {
constructor() {
super();
const propItem = this.props?.route.params.item;
this.state = {
brand : propItem != undefined ? propItem.brand : "",
```

i have tried componentDidMount but it cause infinite loop so does if i uset it in render method

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: no.. data is not being rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

> getDerivedStateFromProps is invoked right before calling the render method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.

Comment: `static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (route.params.item.brand !== state.brand ) {
      return {
        brand : props.route.params.item.brand,
      };
    }
    return null; 
  }`
I get error `route` is not defined

Comment: @MuhammadMuaz use `props.route`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the pros for `constructor` and `super` function.

```js
class Rating extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const propItem = this.props?.route.params.item;

    this.state = {
      brand : propItem != undefined ? propItem.brand : ""
    }
  }

  render() {
    <div></div>
  }
}
```

Comment: tried that. but not working.. brand input remains empty

Comment: if i console propItem at line 5 before defining state, it works only once. and when user comes to this screen again with props it does not console it

Comment: I think you are using the component as Router component. Would you please send me the parent component code?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Rating extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

this.state = {
  brand : this.props?.route.params.item != undefined ? this.props?.route.params.item.brand : ""
}}
render() {
<div></div>
}}
```

you can try like it, make sure your are passing item from previous screen in this.props.navigation